# Inno Setup Compiler - Disable compiler warnings

Tags: inno-setup

Hi there I've been chasing around a method to hide some of the warnings related to translation of some components

```
Warning: Custom message "comp_name" has not been defined for the "de" language. Will use the custom message from the first language in which it was defined: "en".
```

is there anyway to hide them , without manually fix them??

Thanks in advance, 
 BeGiN

Comment: There is no way to suppress those warnings.

Comment: What about fixing these issues? :) E.g. define that message (at least in English if you do not speak German.)

Comment: Yeah , that's what i did eventually but had to do that in 6 different languages :) but the good thing is that i finished :)

Answer (score 0):

If you define your English custom message **without** the `en.` language identifier prefix then it becomes the **default.**

All warnings of this type cease.